# How to flatten image dataset available in train folder before feeding it to neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

folder=r"......\flowerdataset\train1"
path=r"\flowerdataset\train_2"
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
    print("Folder %s created!" % path)
    
else:
    print("Folder %s already exists" % path)

for images in os.listdir(folder):
     img=os.path.join(folder,images)
     img1=cv2.imread(img)
     print(img1.shape)
     img_resized=cv2.resize(img1,(28,28),fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
     gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img_resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, images), gray_img)

new_dat=([])
from keras.layers import Flatten
for img_flat in os.listdir(path):
    img_f=os.path.join(path,img_flat)
    img_fla=np.array(cv2.imread(img_f,0))
    D= img_fla.flatten()
    print(D)
```

Here I am building on simple ANN neural network with 23 images. My dataset has 23 images in train folder and 23 images in test folder. I have preprocessed the train data present in train1 folder and placed it in train_2 folder. Now I want to flatten dataset present in train_2 and get array of 23x784 size(like mnist dataset 60000x784 array)before feeding it to neural network. How can I do this?

I tried by creating empty array and flattening dataset in the loop, but did not work.

Comment: Are you just hoping to use this to send data in as input to your network? Would [the tensorflow image directory loader work for you?](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory), where you could use `color_mode='grayscale'`?